# Goals are not registering in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, problem

I've had a site online for a few weeks, and Google Analytics is working fine. Except Goals, which are not registering for some strange reason.

To be clear: visits to the site are being registered, but no goals are being registered. This is not correct, as people are visiting the goal pages.

I've set up two pages specifically to test this, [Funnel Page](http://www.top10bikefixes.org.uk/Goog_test/goog_test.php) and [Goal Page](http://www.top10bikefixes.org.uk/Goog_test/Goog_test_2.php). (You can visit these, but please do not visit any other pages on the site, as I am performing an experiment and SO referrals would taint results).

Below is a screenshot of `Profiles > Goals` on Analytics.

[image: What I have set up]

Can you see any obvious mistakes I have made? I think I must have missed something really obvious, as this is my first time using Analytics, but I must get this fixed ASAP. It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is step 1 required? Or can people click thru to the Goal URL from another area of your site?

Your Analytics tracking script is outside your `<body>` tag, it's even outside your `<html>` tag

Comment: As shown on the screenshot, the 'Required step' checkbox is un checked. So I think that the answer to your question is no, step 1 is not required.

Comment: I updated my answer fix your js

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. Visits to the site are registering despite this, however maybe this could stop goals from registering. I have now moved the analytics tracking code to be inside the `<body>`. I will update the question tomorrow to report if any goals have/ have not registered.

Comment: It worked! I **knew** I just missed something dumb like that. So if your analytics javascript is outside the `<html>` tags the hits count but the goals don't register. Thank you so much!